# Java RTSP client/server library

Tags: java, media, rtsp

Is anyone aware about good RTSP client/server Java library?

Search on Google reveals JMF, which is very outdated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

If you're *still* interested, [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) provides RTSP support since version 3.2.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Netty NIO framework to write your own RTSP server / client implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Gstreamer. I have created a Java code for RTSP Client. And also posted link on RTSP server [rtsp streaming on java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039801/rtsp-streaming-on-java/7475559#7475559)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/). It's a set of libraries that wrap a lot of modern codecs in Java interfaces.

Comment: I actually familiar with this, but it doesn't support RTSP :(.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: FMJ was ahead of its time but hasn't been touched in probably 3+ years. Their ffmpeg implementation was really out-of-date when I tried to use it several years ago, go with Xuggler.

Answer (score 1):

There is no java implementation of RTSP protocol. You must do it yourself using a NIO framework (MINA, GRIZZLY, NETTY...)  its a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Red5 has some support or is going to have support for RTSP and is Java based.

Comment: Red5 is RTMP, not RTSP. They are *completely* different. (Granted, they are both streaming protocols, but apart from that, completely different.)

Comment: I posted about Red5 RTP/RTSP in the similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193837/java-rtp-rtcp-library-using-nio

Answer (score 1):

And, as I think you know already, you can use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) :)

Comment: What does Xuggler have to do with RTSP?

Answer (score 1):

you can use vlc(Videolan client) whith vlcj and JNA

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I've coded android rtsp streaming client (android could stream to media server, wowza in that particular case). There are only couple tricky moments with that approach:

- it was based on known trick with unix sockets and parsing mp4
  generated by the device in order to get NALU out of it;
- timestamps synchronisation for audio and video is really not trivial
  on android when two media recorders used (for vide and for audio) for getting the media.