# Java RTP/RTCP library using NIO

Tags: java, nio, rtp, rtcp

Is there a Java RTP/RTCP library based on Java NIO or some Java NIO framework (Netty, MINA, ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Red5, we are adapting an RTP/RTSP library written using Mina. If you would like to check it out, go here: http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/plugins/trunk/rtspplugin/

The original library was written by Matteo Merli (matteo.merli@gmail.com) and yes, we have his permission to modify it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But the RTP part of the library seems not to contain the actual RTP/RTCP handlers, just packet classes, or am I mistaken?

Comment: I was under the impression that everything needed was there. I am not absolutely sure of this however.

Comment: @PaulGregoire link is not working.

Comment: Updated links for Red5 and RTSP: https://github.com/Red5/red5-plugins/tree/master/rtspplugin and https://github.com/Red5/red5-rtsp-restreamer

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write a wrapper yourself, I'm afraid. Netty has a pretty flexible architecture that would allow that.