# RTP/RTSP library usable in Java

Tags: java, rtsp, rtp

I'm looking to write a voip application, I know JMF has RTP code but it's old and 32bit only. Is there a robust library that does RTP/RTSP that can be used with java?

Thanks

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193837/java-rtp-rtcp-library-using-nio

Answer (score 3):

no way JMF - its 10 years out of date

list java RTP RTSP packages:
RTSPClientLib.tar.gz  on code.google
http://github.com/brunodecarvalho/efflux

i used the efflux on a java project and it was worth the time learning his packages. The combined netty/efflux is very robust on the variety of RFC's involved in networking underlying RTSP/RTP.

i think i have an eclipse project archived somewhere using efflux for alot of RTSP dialog type stuff.

Comment: his test are here: https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/efflux/tree/master/src/test/java

Comment: The link is broken