# Java Plugin for RTMP Streaming

Tags: java, coldfusion, video-streaming, rtmp

I'm trying to locate a Java plugin that I can include in my ColdFusion project that will connect to an RTMP stream for video and audio. This way, I can avoid Flash until HTML5 is up to speed.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820888/java-rtsp-client-server-library

Comment: Java plug in until HTML 5 is up to speed?  Java applet penetration floats somewhere around 60% whereas flash is around 97%.  Unless you have a really solid and specific reason for avoiding flash, why would you? I could see targeting iOS with HTML5, but Java certainly isn't the answer in that case... - I can't think of significant market segment you'd be targeting that is java applet enabled, but not flash.

Comment: @Nate, my question isn't that deep. Simply looking at all of the options. I'm a Flash developer of 10 years...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its specifically what you want, but http://flazr.com/ may work? Looked at it awhile back so not sure what state it is in the modern day, but it sounds like it could work in applet format.